# sending Http request from request message programatically - HTTP DATASET CSIC 2010

Tags: command-line, https

I have HTTP request messages

something like This:-

[example message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dHAr.png)

Instead of making messages from HTTP-client libraries, I need to send this Http message to the server to test.
I have a large dataset of messages to I need to send programmatically.

for only one message I can use

telnet [destinationip] [port]

to establish TCP connection and type this message. but for the big dataset, I can't test manually.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: To make it easier to answer it would be great if you provide information like that HTTP request as text in your question instead of a screenshot. I could not add the full URL to my answer because of that. Well, I could have, but I would have had to type it. Where it text I could have just copied it.

Comment: For that reason, I provided dataset in Subject. So that others can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `curl`. Depending on which of the HTTP headers you really need you have to construct your command. You can add a header to the command using `-H 'Accept-Language: en'`. Multiple headers just repeat this argument. I recommend reading the `man` page of `curl`. As you have `&` sign in your urls you need to quote the url in order to prevent the shell from interpreting the `&` signs as background process.

```
curl -H 'Accept-Language: en' 'http://localhost:8080/tienda1/public/anadir...'
```